# filter values in dropdown

Tags: search, filter

I have a dropdown list with a lot of values and I want to give the users the option to filter these values with a search input field, something like this:

[image: filter example]

So if the user types chicken in the search input field dropdown will only contain meals that contain the word chicken. However I don't think this is good user experience, what do you guys think? any alternative suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't combine the search bar and droplist into an ordinary combobox?

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to place the search inside of the dropdown, much like how StackExchange does:

[image]

Currently the part that seems a bit odd in your design is the search is affecting the contents of the dropdown - the problem being that you don't see the affects of your search until you click the dropdown. Then if someone wants to modify the search the dropdown gets hidden when they start modifying the search term.

The advantage of displaying the search in the dropdown would be that you could provide immediate filtering which would lead to a lot faster use since with instant filtering you often only type the first few letters of what you are thinking.